# context.textAlign isn't working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm a beginner and the code inside the script which is called `context.textAlign = "centre";` isn't moving `"Sample Text"` to the centre of the canvas border which is made by css so am i doing something wrong or am i missing something etc. Thanks

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html5 canvas text</title>
  <style>
    #testCanvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> canvas text </h1>

  <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="300">Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;

      context.textAlign = "centre";
      context.font = "Bold 60pt Arial";
      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';
      context.fillText("Sample Text", x, y);
      context.strokeStyle = "green";
      context.lineWidth = 3;
      context.strokeText("Sample Text", x, y);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong Typo:
It is "center" and not "centre".

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html5 canvas text</title>
  <style>
    #testCanvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> canvas text </h1>

  <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="300">Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;

      context.textAlign = "center";
      context.font = "Bold 60pt Arial";
      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';
      context.fillText("Sample Text", x, y);
      context.strokeStyle = "green";
      context.lineWidth = 3;
      context.strokeText("Sample Text", x, y);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `textAlign` from `centre` to `center`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html5 canvas text</title>
  <style>
    #testCanvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> canvas text </h1>

  <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="300">Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;

      context.textAlign = "center";
      context.font = "Bold 60pt Arial";
      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';
      context.fillText("Sample Text", x, y);
      context.strokeStyle = "green";
      context.lineWidth = 3;
      context.strokeText("Sample Text", x, y);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry for my question i am so dumb

Comment: @ShayanRazavi Happens :). Just remember to flag your question as answered so we can handle it as done.